# How to implement a checkbox in to a keyboard in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I've built a simple storeHelper app (you can write which products you need to buy, when and in which store) and I want to add a function of adding a checkbox as a user to mark what you've bought from the list, like in a SamsungNotes app, how can I do it + how do I need to change a database to save the status of checkbox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the checkbox from the Palette in Android Studio, checkbox is available inside the button section in the palette. About the Firebase connection I only know about how to save the user credentials in the database I have no idea about the checkbox status.

Answer (score 0):

@Serg Do provide more details on what database you want to use as the question is very vague. Also, do check the documentation for [checkbox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiso4PSmrD4AhWCILcAHbj5DGUQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fui%2Fcontrols%2Fcheckbox&usg=AOvVaw23hv6YI_i6OomLabywoWYr) and try it out first.

@Manthan For checkbox status it can be stored into Firestore as a field in a document which belongs to the user. Do check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).